# compile errors after upgrading to latest CRA

Tags: create-react-app, react-pdf

I just updated to latest create-react-app (web pack 5).  And am now getting the following errors (I'm just showing the first 2 errors here).  Any help explaining what this error means and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.  I don't think the problem is with react-pdf because I created a new create-react-app project that uses that package and there's no problem.

{
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-pdf/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/inherits.js 1:0-46

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './setPrototypeOf' in '/Users/bob/dev/workbox-web/node_modules/react-pdf/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm'
Did you mean 'setPrototypeOf.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './setPrototypeOf' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-pdf/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutProperties.js 1:0-74

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './objectWithoutPropertiesLoose' in '/Users/bob/dev/workbox-web/node_modules/react-pdf/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm'
Did you mean 'objectWithoutPropertiesLoose.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './objectWithoutPropertiesLoose' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
}

Answer (score 3):

Somehow I was accessing a wrong version of babel after CRA upgrade to 5.  Deleting node_modules and re-installing was not enough.  I needed to delete node_modules and yarn.lock and then yarn install - and then all was ok.

Comment: Same for me, but with `npm` instead of `yarn`.  I'd already tried deleting `node-modules` and re-doing the `npm install` but it didn't work.  I had to delete `node_modules` AND `package-lock.json` before doing the `npm install`.  After that the build worked fine. I wouldn't have thought of that - thanks!